# External site in FXM not appearing in Sitecore Experience Analytics

Tags: fxm

I am using sitecore 9.1 and added a site in FXM. But that site is not showing in Experience Analytics.
I am testing this in my local environment. Both sites are running using HTTPS. The external site is also running locally in IIS. The following link has the rule set up.
https://prnt.sc/tsxk91

Please let me know what am I missing that the site in not showing in Experience Analytics.

Comment: Have you tried following the steps mentioned in Official documentation?
1. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/add-an-external-website-in-fxm.html

2. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/view-the-analytics-reports-for-fxm-websites.html

Comment: Thanks Paul for your response. Yes I have already tried the steps mentioned in the url you have provided.